# Is MS Multilingual App Toolkit campatible with Windows 7?

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-4, multilingual

I would like to use Microsoft Multilingual App Toolkit in a MVC 4 application. 

I followed the steps as suggested in [Dammann's](http://damsteen.nl/blog/using-the-microsoft-multilingual-app-toolkit-with-asp.net-mvc-or-any-other-.net-project-type) article, but I cannot build the project.

It fails with the error message:` Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\es\LanguageTest.resources.dll" because it was not found." for the not neutral languages using the .xlf file.

Reading on Microsoft [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh848309.aspx) it states:

```
Supported platforms
Windows 8 32-bit or 64-bit editions
Windows Phone SDK 8.0
```

So there is not compatibility at all with windows 7? Meaning that I canot use that toolkit in a normal MVC web application even if I setup manually the web project (as indicated in Dammann's blog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Multilingual App Toolkit Visual Studio integration is not support on Windows 7.  The Toolkit only supports Windows 7 for the XLIFF editing experience.